# Luxon: Cannot assign luxon DateTime when it's created from ISO string

Tags: typescript, luxon

When I create a luxon DateTime object from the `fromISO` method, seems like it cannot be assigned to `DateTime` properly.

e.g.

```
let datetime: DateTime = DateTime.fromISO(isoString);
```

does not compile with the error:

```
Type 'DateTime<true> | DateTime<false>' is not assignable to type 'DateTime<boolean>'.
  Type 'DateTime<true>' is missing the following properties from type 'DateTime<boolean>': isWeekend, localWeekday, localWeekNumber, localWeekYear, weeksInLocalWeekYear
```

What is a proper way to construct DateTime from ISO string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat complicated one. I'll provide some explanation below, but — in short — you can avoid the issue either by:

- not using an explicit [annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables), and instead simply rely on TypeScript's inference when initializing your variable:

  [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQbgXzgDMoIQ4AiAGwFcAPCAOwoG4AoNgYyYGd5geEAMowowRgHM4AXkoAmAAwBGAOwBaBQFY1SzVgUAOAFwBmBUYULWbKhngATeLLSYcIDADoSZAJJCA8gAUAsKi4hIAlOwA9NFwcAB6APxsQA)

  ```ts
  import { DateTime } from "luxon";

  const isoString = "2017-05-15T08:30:00";
  let dt = DateTime.fromISO(isoString);
  //  ^? let dt: DateTime<true> | DateTime<false>
  ```
- or you can use the exported type alias [`DateTimeMaybeValid`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c69f4e570ea321a8f1bd9859ed4a3ffb7c1cf701/types/luxon/src/datetime.d.ts#L398) to annotate the instance:

  [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQYDRwwCeYGK62uAsqkQEYYBqqANsACZwC+cAZlBBBwARCwCuADwgA7YQG4AUAoDGMgM7xgaiAGUYUYNIDmcALwiATAAYAjAHYAtFYCsDm86xWAHAC4AzFY+VlbyCiwY8OwwPuSYOCAYNPRMrBxmsZQJAHT8ggCSOgDyABRauvqGRgCUigD0tXBwAHoA-ApAA)

  ```ts
  import { DateTime, type DateTimeMaybeValid } from "luxon";

  const isoString = "2017-05-15T08:30:00";
  let dt: DateTimeMaybeValid = DateTime.fromISO(isoString);
  //  ^? let dt: DateTime<true> | DateTime<false>
  ```

---

More:

Luxon has a concept of [validity](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/validity). By default, DateTimes fail silently instead of throwing exceptions, and the validity information is stored on the DateTime instances. Here's an example:

```html
<script type="module">

import { DateTime } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/es6/luxon.js";

for (const input of ["2017-05-15T08:30:00", "tomorrow"]) {
  const dt = DateTime.fromISO(input);
  const { isValid, invalidExplanation, invalidReason } = dt;
  const text = dt.toString();
  console.log({ input, isValid, invalidReason, invalidExplanation, text });
}

</script>
```

However, [Luxon can be configured to throw](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/validity?id=throwoninvalid) in cases where an invalid DateTime would be produced:

```html
<script type="module">

import { DateTime, Settings } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.4.4/build/es6/luxon.js";

Settings.throwOnInvalid = true;

for (const input of ["2017-05-15T08:30:00", "tomorrow"]) {
  try {
    const dt = DateTime.fromISO(input);
    const text = dt.toString();
    console.log({ input, valid: true, text });
  } catch (cause) {
    console.log({ input, valid: false });
    console.error(cause);
  }
}

</script>
```

In the type system, [`DateTime` is generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdf38f276d25e12de1d7cf2d38749aa38e6b804c/types/luxon/src/datetime.d.ts#L427) in an attempt to encode the validity state so that the compiler can use it to narrow:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQIYwKYBVQbgXzgDMoIQ4AiAGwFcAPCAOwoG4AoNo6OACgGMmAZ3jBGYGvAhE4AbQoAmAAwBGAOwBaRQFZ1yrVkUAOAFwBmRccWKKAGkowy0UgHcKAXQCUiNgEgBjYTgAE3gAXhR0bFwAOhIyAEkAZQB5HlFxGA92H2BpHhDo4EEANVQqYCCvBF8fAtEANzKKgCUMVEEmGoB6LrgAPQB+GrrGRvKggFE6MCpURnRgTp8fHv6hn0IMKkE8auWRsZa2jsZu3sHhmELRpsnp2fmYRdPl1YuNtnw2IA)

```ts
for (const input of ["2017-05-15T08:30:00", "tomorrow"]) {
  const dt = DateTime.fromISO(input);
  if (dt.isValid) {
    dt.invalidReason
    // ^? (property) DateTime<true>.invalidReason: null
    dt.invalidExplanation
    // ^? (property) DateTime<true>.invalidExplanation: null
  } else {
    dt.invalidReason
    // ^? (property) DateTime<false>.invalidReason: string
    dt.invalidExplanation
    // ^? (property) DateTime<false>.invalidExplanation: string | null
  }
}
```

> Note: You can inform the TypeScript compiler that you enabled the exception-throwing option (above): [1](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdf38f276d25e12de1d7cf2d38749aa38e6b804c/types/luxon/src/settings.d.ts#L57-L69), [2](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bdf38f276d25e12de1d7cf2d38749aa38e6b804c/types/luxon/src/settings.d.ts#L84-L90)

Comment: It looks like these changes were introduced in [DefinitelyTyped#64995](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/64995) and [DefinitelyTyped#65078](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/65078)

Comment: Thanks. I will probably enable the throw on error option as I validate the ISO string in a separate path :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check separately whether the parsing succeeded. As an example:

```js
let datetime = DateTime.fromISO(isoString); // type: DateTime<true> | DateTime<false>

// check if parsing succeeded
if (!datetime.isValid) {
  // cancel the operation because the date time is invalid
  return
}

const validTime = datetime; // type: DateTime<true>
```

I'm not sure when this was changed, I can not find it in the [changelog](https://github.com/moment/luxon/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) or the [documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetime) of luxon. If someone knows where this change is from then I'd love to know

edit: there's a lot more information in the answer of @jsejcksn